# amsthm: combination of title and label gives problem

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsthm, showkeys

After years I have had this problem I discovered today the direct cause, but I would like to understand why it happens and **how** I avoid the error.

I **still can't make a MEW** and that is the reason why I never posted a question, but perhaps with the following information someone can help me.

The following piece of code:

```
\begin{example}[Gravitational potential of a homogeneous spherical shell]\label{ex:grav-pot-sphere-shell} 
We consider a shell with inner radius $R_i$, outer radius $R_o$ and density $\rho$.
```

produces the following wrong alignment:

[image]

If I remove the label:

```
\begin{example}[Gravitational potential of a homogeneous spherical shell]
We consider a shell with inner radius $R_i$, outer radius $R_o$ and density $\rho$.
```

The alignment problem disappears:

[image]

> (1) Why it happens? (2) How do I can use labels and avoid the alignment problem?

**EDIT 1** If I put the label after the first word the alignment is fine, but this is not a solution since the label then points to the second line.

**EDIT 2** After inserting `\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}`:

[image]

Text width: `\documentclass[10pt,titlepage,twoside]{book}` unchanged

**EDIT 3** The problem is caused by `\usepackage{showkeys}`

Comment: Just a guess: add `%` after the label to suppress possible spurious space.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan Thank you for the suggestion. I checked it and it does not work

Comment: @SergeiGolovan I can even put everything on the same line without spaces and the problem persists.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with a minimal number of packages (only amsthm and geometry to set up page width). Probably some other package interferes in your document. You might try to add `\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}` and build with lualatex. This way you can visually see if the problem is indeed with spaces.

Comment: Without knowing the text width you're using it's impossible to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan I added a screen shot with the lua visual debug

Comment: @egreg I use \documentclass[10pt,titlepage,twoside]{book} without changing the margins

Comment: @SergeiGolovan Your suggestion brought me to the solution: the problem is `\usepackage{showkeys}` THANK YOU!!

Comment: @PeptideChain If you're using `showkeys` you're certainly during the document preparation phase, when you should not be concerned with line and page breaks. It's completely useless to be, because even small edits to the text can change breaks.

Comment: @PeptideChain maybe you can use this information to create an MWE, and then add a self-answer without the package that addresses the issue. That makes the question more useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the presence of the package `showkeys`.

A MWE for the solution:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Some}
\section{Introduction}

\setcounter{theorem}{112}
\par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{example}[A very very very very very very very very very long title]\label{ex:something}
We consider a shell with inner radius $R_i$, outer radius $R_o$ and density $\rho$.
We consider a shell with inner radius $R_i$, outer radius $R_o$ and density $\rho$.
\end{example}
\par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\end{document}
```

Result with the use of the package `showkeys`:
[image]

Result removing `showkeys`:
[image]